# ruby: how to remove a migration that has a table update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-migration

I have taken over a ruby application that has used a few migrations to update data in a column.
Is there a way of removing this from the migration without affecting any ruby rollbacks in the migration.

thanks
maggs

Comment: As a general rule, you don't want to go editing migrations after they've already been run. Any future dev work should load up the schema rather than run through all the migrations. Is there any reason that you need to edit those migrations?

Answer (score 0):

If the migration has already run and you don't need to use it anymore you can simply delete it.  As stated in the comments to your initial post, deleting / editing migrations after they've run is generally not advisable, but there is a place for it.

It would be important to understand what else is happening in the migration you are referring to and how likely it is to cause problems.

Another possible solution is to adjust the update to make it idempotent - i.e. no matter how many times it  is run, it shouldn't change the outcome.  This could take the form of an `if` statement.  In pseudocode

```
class SomeMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    Score.each do |s|
      do_some_stuff if s.value == 1
    end
  end

  def down
    Score.each do |s|
      revert_some_stuff if s.value == 0
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi the update migrations shouldn't hurt as the values already updated should remain the same but just incase a value is changed by someone then I don't want to change it back when I run the migration. As for making the update impotent what would be the best way to do this for update where all the records of a table have been updated. the answers you have given are valuable so many thanks maggs

Comment: So, point of minor clarity, idempotent is the word!  Impotent is rather different :P

As for the best way to make sure things aren't changed, you'd need to come up with the logic to tell Ruby when to perform the action and when not to.  Unless you can express that programatically, I can't see how it would be done.